# Implementing Facebook Like and Tweet Buttons into E-Mail

Tags: facebook, email, marketing, social-media, twitter

I am sending an email campaign out to subscribers and I would like to incorporate a Facebook Like and a Tweet Button into my email. Since I cannot use javascript inside emails I was wondering the best way to do this. Here is what I have so far:

**Tweet Button**

```
<a title="Share Via Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
url=http://my-campaign-url&amp;text=My%20Text%20-%20&amp;via=My Name&amp;">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/tweet-button-small.png" 
style="border:0 none;" alt="Share Via Twitter">
```

**Facebook Like**

```
<a title="Like this on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.
php?href=http://my-campaign-url.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=
false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=427%20">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/fblike-button-small.png" style="border: 
0 none;" alt="Like This on Facebook">
```

Here are a few questions:

How do I pull the subject of the email to be posted along with the content?

Is it possible to pull only an image from the email and have that posted vs the entire email content?

Is there a better way to code the above buttons?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: What software you using to send the emails?

Comment: I use a CMS to handle the mailing. I build the code in HTML then paste it into their Editor and off it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Facebook Like buttons are for web pages only. On e-mails you can create share links (and use images as buttons).

The code would be:

FACEBOOK:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A//my.campaign.url"><img src="http://absolute.path.to/fblike-button-small.png" style="border: 
0 none;" alt="Like This on Facebook"></a>
```

Facebook sums "shares" to Likes count.

TWITTER:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/?status=My%20tweet%20http%3A//www.mysite.com"><img src="http://absolute.path.to/tweet-button-small.png" style="border: 
0 none;" alt="Tweet this"></a>
```

NOTE:

Your website URL and the Twitter message have to be URL encoded for both Facebook and Twitter links. There are tools to help with URL encoding. Click this link to search them in Google:

http://www.google.com/search?q=urlencode+tool

Comment: Thanks, I found this last night: https://www.addthis.com/get-addthis and this does what you say but a bit easier as a tool =>